# Load content from Ajax-loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I can load content with Ajax to my project, but the content also has Ajax calls to the same function. But these calls don't work.

```
$(function cargar_ajax(){
$(".call_cuerpo").on("click",function(){
    var content_id = $(this).data("id")
    //~ console.log(content_id)
    $.ajax({
        url: "/get_content?content_id="+content_id,
        }).done(function(res) {
            $( '.contenido_ajax' ).html(res);
            });
    });
});
```

I read that you must call the function after loading content but not how or where.

This is my div in HTML:

```
<div class="contenido_ajax"></div>
```

A working Ajax call:

```
<li><a href="#" class="call_cuerpo" data-id="1"><small>Load ajax content</small></a></li>
```

This call doesn't work if it's loaded with Ajax:

```
<li><a href="#" class="call_cuerpo" data-id="{{ item.content_id }}@{{ item.book_id }}">{{ item.code }}</a></li>
```

The code is loaded from an Ajax call.

Note: I'm using: Django 1.6 + bootstrap 3.2 + html 5

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `.call_cuerpo` elements are being dynamically appended to the DOM you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$('.contenido_ajax').on('click', '.call_cuerpo', function() {
    // rest of your code...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right, your click-event is not executed when its loaded via ajax ?
Try:

```
$("document").on("click", ".call_cuerpo",function(){ ...
```

for your click-event

Comment: Do not use `body` for delegated event handlers. Styling can make it not respond to click events. `document` is the safest fallback if nothing is closer.

Answer (score 0):

Try as my code below tested in my local apache server.  event.preventDefault() to prevent the default functionality occuring from link element.

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".call_cuerpo").click(function(event){
           // alert("I am working");
            event.preventDefault();

        var content_id = $(this).data("id")
        //~ console.log(content_id)
        $.ajax({
            url: "./get_content.php?content_id="+content_id
        }).done(function(res) {
            $( '.contenido_ajax' ).html(res);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Output:
[image: ajax_html_load_output]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and sorry for taking so long to answer.

Indeed the problem is: **it does not run when called from ajax content.**

After reading [this](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on) the problem is not able to delegate the event.

This is the html code that is not called (previously loaded from ajax):

```
<a class="call_cuerpo" data-id="A0300306@1" href="#">03.06</a>
```

Must be loaded in this django template.html:

```
{% block book_content %}
<div class="contenido_ajax"></div>
{% endblock book_content %}
```

I have simplified the function like this:

```
$(function load_ajax(){
    $(".call_cuerpo").on("click", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var content_id = $(this).data("id")
        // console.log(content_id)
        $( ".contenido_ajax" ).load( "/get_content?content_id="+content_id );
    });
});
```

I tried several syntax and the event goes down.

I Try:

```
$(function load_ajax(){
    $(".call_cuerpo").on("click", "contenido_ajax", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var content_id = $(this).data("id")
        console.log(content_id)
        $( ".contenido_ajax" ).load( "/get_content?content_id="+content_id );
    });
});
```

And:

```
$(function load_ajax(){
    $(".contenido_ajax").on("click", ".call_cuerpo", function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        var content_id = $(this).data("id")
        console.log(content_id)
        $( ".contenido_ajax" ).load( "/get_content?content_id="+content_id );
    });
});
```

But that does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

PD: Sorry for my english